# Symfony3 : Inject several @doctrine.orm.entity_manager in a service

Tags: symfony

I work with [several connexion](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Here is my config.yml :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: connexion_1# specify the connexion used by default
        connections:
            connexion_1:
                driver:   "%database_driver1%"  
                 ....
            connexion_2:
                driver:    "%database_driver2%" 
                 ...
```

I want to inject 2 connexion entity manager in a service.

In my service.yml i can just inject one entity_manager named "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" . This is the default manager

```
@doctrine.orm.entity_manager argument
    zip_command:
        class: BackEndBundle\Command\ZipCommand
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
        tags:
            -  { name: console.command }
```

How can inject an other connexion ?

Comment: "bin/console debug:container | grep doctrine" will show you how entity manager services are named.  The default manager is just an alias.  And make sure you understand the difference between an entity manager and a dbal database connection.  Refer to the docs on how to configure multiple entity managers if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

According to documentation you should be able to inject your custom entity managers via `doctrine.orm.{entity_manager_name_here}_entity_manager` alias. You can find your entity managers' name under `doctrine.orm.entity_managers` in config.yml.

### Option 2

If you want to have access to all of your entity managers in your service, you could inject the `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry` directly and use `getManager(s)` methods.